# Android, пропадают данные в HashMap

Tags: java, android, java-hashmap

Задание такое: парсим данные и закидываем их в HashMap. При записи они есть, но при чтении их нет! Что делать, помогите пожалуйста! Буду благодарен за любую подсказку! Код, где мы записываем данные в коллекцию:

```
 private void addModelToList(ReplaceModel model, List<ReplaceModel> list) {
        list.add(model);
        Log.e("samuliak", "list.get(0).getGroup: "+list.get(0).getGroup());
        Log.e("samuliak", "model: : "+model.toString());
        if (!listOfObj.containsKey(list.get(0).getGroup()))
            listOfObj.put(list.get(0).getGroup(), list);
        else {

            List<ReplaceModel> rm = listOfObj.get(list.get(0).getGroup())
                    .subList(0, listOfObj.get(list.get(0).getGroup()).size());
            Log.e("samuliak", "rm.size(): : "+rm.size());
            for (ReplaceModel r : rm)
                list.add(r);
            listOfObj.put(list.get(0).getGroup(), list);
        }
        listModel.add(list);
        list.clear();
        Log.e("samuliak", "listofObj.size(): : "+listOfObj.size());
        Log.e("samuliak", "listofObj.values().size: : "+listOfObj.values().size());
    }
```

А вот код где мы считываем из него данные:

```
 private void initCardViewInfo() {
        GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridGroup);
        assert gridLayout != null;
        gridLayout.removeAllViews();
        Button btnGroup;
        int typeSize = display.getHeight()/135;
        int total = listGroup.size();
        int column = 4;
        int row = total / column;
        gridLayout.setColumnCount(column);
        gridLayout.setRowCount(row + 1);

        for(int i = 0, c = 0, r = 0; i < total; i++,c++){
            if(c == column) {
                c = 0;
                r++;
            }
            GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
            param.height = display.getHeight() / 15;
            param.width = display.getWidth() / (column+2);
            param.rightMargin = 5;
            if (c == 0){
                param.leftMargin = display.getWidth() / (column+4);
            }
            if (c+1 == column){
                param.rightMargin = display.getWidth() / (column+4);
            }
            param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(c);
            param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(r);

            btnGroup = new Button(this);
            btnGroup.setText(listGroup.get(i));
            btnGroup.setTextSize(typeSize);
            btnGroup.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            btnGroup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("samuliak", "Click is OK");
                    //CardView cardReplace = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardReplace);
                    //assert cardReplace != null;
                    //cardReplace.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    LinearLayout linearReplace = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearReplace);
                    for (List<ReplaceModel> list : listModel) {
                        Log.e("samuliak", "list size: "+list.size());
                        for (ReplaceModel m : list) {
                            Log.e("samuliak", "ReplaceModel m: " + m.toString());
                            if (((Button) v).getText() == m.getGroup()) {
                                Log.e("samuliak", "Find getText: " + m.getGroup());
                                int typeSize = display.getHeight() / 135;
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams param = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                param.height = display.getHeight() / 15;
                                param.width = display.getWidth() / 6;
                                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.proverka);
                                tv.setText("Text from code");
//                                TextView tv = new TextView(v.getContext());
//                                tv.setText(m.toString());
//                                tv.setTextSize(typeSize);
                                //tv.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                                Log.e("samuliak", "tv.toString(): " + tv.toString());
                                assert linearReplace != null;
//                                linearReplace.addView(tv);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            btnGroup.setLayoutParams(param);
            gridLayout.addView(btnGroup);
```

Логика такая: во внутреннем классе мы парсим данные и помещаем их в коллекцию, в основном классе мы добавляем на кнопки слушатели, при которых выводим нужную нам информацию из этой же коллекции. А в итоге у неё есть объекты (в нашем случаи это список объектов), но они пустые. Проверил при добавлении, все есть, добавляет, но почему то они затираются (

}

Comment: локализуйте проблему, никому ваша простыня из 500 строк кода не нужна. Сами с ней разбирайтесь.

Comment: Хорошо, я вас понял. Вот постараюсь все кратко объяснить:

Comment: Большое спасибо Roman Novoselov, помогло!)

Comment: Поставь галочку тогда, тебе ничего не стоит, а мне рейтинг ;)

Answer (score 2):

Из предоставленного листинга не понятно почему так происходит.

Но судя по описанию проблемы могу предположить, что запись и чтение из HashMap происходит в разных потоках.

Если моя догадка верна, используй ключевое слово volatile при объявлении HashMap

```
public voilatile HashMap myHashMap;
```

> Когда переменная объявлена как volatile, любая запись её будет
>   осуществляться прямо в память, минуя кеш. Также как и считываться
>   будет прямо из памяти, а не из всевозможного кеша. Это значит, что все
>   потоки будут "видеть" одно и то же значение переменной одновременно.